# What if somebody use few valuable seconds of your YT video?

Tags: youtube

Some youtuber used few seconds of my footage in his video.
I discovered it randomly, he haven't even contacted me.
He say that if he credit me in description, it's already okay according the YT comunity.

The footage he stealed was bought by several TV companies as it's about the place where most people never been to, so it has some value.

I really can not do anything?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a copyright takedown request on YouTube:

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2807622?hl=en

They may be protected under [Fair Use](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9783148?hl=en) or Fair Dealing rules.